# Out of Memory Exception Ionic Zip Extraction

Tags: c#-4.0, zip

I am download a large zip file and trying to extract its contents (a csv file) into a memory stream.

This works for smaller files but for larger ones (mine is currently 16mb) I get OutOfMemoryException.
So at this point I have the memory stream which consists of the zip file.

```
 using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(memoryStream))
                {
                     zip.ParallelDeflateThreshold = -1;
                     zip[csvKey].Extract(csvFile);
                }
```

I am using the Ionic library to manage the zip. From reading other stackover flow posts I added ParallelDeflateThreshold to -1. But I am still having the same issue.

I am currently on a 16gb RAM i7 machine, so memory should not be an issue. Running on IIS express but the same happens on regular IIS.

Any help is much appreciated as I ran out of ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to avoid storing the file in memory. Applications have a 1.2GB limit on memory usage. Then 64bit applications have 2GB+ I believe.

I'm not 100% sure but this might work:

```
using ZipFile;
new ZipFile(memoryStream).ExtractToDirectory(csvFile, extractPath);;
```